# Apply specifc CSS class to the second Span with a specific CSS class

Tags: html, css

I need to apply specific background color to the second span with class "ui-steps-number" but the css class I'm trying to implement its ignored:

## CSS

```
.ui-steps-number:nth-child(2) {
    background-color: yellow !important;
}
```

## html

```
<ul role="tablist">
    <li class="ui-steps-item ui-state-highlight" ng-reflect-klass="ui-steps-item" ng-reflect-ng-class="[object Object]">
        <a class="ui-menuitem-link">
            <span class="ui-steps-number">1</span>
            <span class="ui-steps-title">QUALIFICATION</span>
        </a>
    </li><li class="ui-steps-item ui-state-default" ng-reflect-klass="ui-steps-item" ng-reflect-ng-class="[object Object]">
        <a class="ui-menuitem-link">
            <span class="ui-steps-number">2</span>
            <span class="ui-steps-title">ANALYSIS</span>
        </a>
    </li><li class="ui-steps-item ui-state-default" ng-reflect-klass="ui-steps-item" ng-reflect-ng-class="[object Object]">
        <a class="ui-menuitem-link">
            <span class="ui-steps-number">3</span>
            <span class="ui-steps-title">QUOTE</span>
        </a>
    </li><li class="ui-steps-item ui-state-default" ng-reflect-klass="ui-steps-item" ng-reflect-ng-class="[object Object]">
        <a class="ui-menuitem-link">
            <span class="ui-steps-number">4</span>
            <span class="ui-steps-title">NEGOTIATION</span>
        </a>
    </li><li class="ui-steps-item ui-state-default" ng-reflect-klass="ui-steps-item" ng-reflect-ng-class="[object Object]">
        <a class="ui-menuitem-link">
            <span class="ui-steps-number">5</span>
            <span class="ui-steps-title">CLOSED</span>
        </a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Thanks to support

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to address the second `<li>`

```css
.ui-steps-item:nth-child(2) .ui-steps-number {
    background-color: yellow !important;
}
```

```html
<ul role="tablist">
    <li class="ui-steps-item ui-state-highlight" ng-reflect-klass="ui-steps-item" ng-reflect-ng-class="[object Object]">
        <a class="ui-menuitem-link">
            <span class="ui-steps-number">1</span>
            <span class="ui-steps-title">QUALIFICATION</span>
        </a>
    </li><li class="ui-steps-item ui-state-default" ng-reflect-klass="ui-steps-item" ng-reflect-ng-class="[object Object]">
        <a class="ui-menuitem-link">
            <span class="ui-steps-number">2</span>
            <span class="ui-steps-title">ANALYSIS</span>
        </a>
    </li><li class="ui-steps-item ui-state-default" ng-reflect-klass="ui-steps-item" ng-reflect-ng-class="[object Object]">
        <a class="ui-menuitem-link">
            <span class="ui-steps-number">3</span>
            <span class="ui-steps-title">QUOTE</span>
        </a>
    </li><li class="ui-steps-item ui-state-default" ng-reflect-klass="ui-steps-item" ng-reflect-ng-class="[object Object]">
        <a class="ui-menuitem-link">
            <span class="ui-steps-number">4</span>
            <span class="ui-steps-title">NEGOTIATION</span>
        </a>
    </li><li class="ui-steps-item ui-state-default" ng-reflect-klass="ui-steps-item" ng-reflect-ng-class="[object Object]">
        <a class="ui-menuitem-link">
            <span class="ui-steps-number">5</span>
            <span class="ui-steps-title">CLOSED</span>
        </a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
.ui-steps-item:nth-child(2) .ui-steps-number {
      background-color: yellow !important;
}
```